# Questions about texture compression

Tags: unity

So when I choose the texture in the Inspector window I see three tabs: Default, Standalones & Android. I can choose some variants of how to compress this texture, but:

- My texture is a png (so it's RGBA). When I click the Default->Format I can see stuff like **Alpha 8, R 8, RGB 24** bit. So if I choose **R8**, for example, does that mean that my **GBA** channels will be thrown away?
- What is the **Max Size**? My texture is **600x375.** If I choose **512** will it clip my texture to **512x375** or what? And why it is called ***Max*** Size if I am working with a single texture right now?
- If I choose Default->Format to **Automatic** and **does not do any override on any specific platform** will Unity choose default texture compression formats for a specific platform using [this table?](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You lose data based on the compression limits. [R8 will not preserve
  your RGB
  data](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.R8.html).
- Max size is the upper limit of the exported texture. If your size is
  below it, nothing changes. [If your texture is above max size then
  it's down scaled to match the max size values](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html).
- Unity should be able to pick the correct format, the current
  compression should show up along side the texture preview. Some cases require you to set the proper settings yourself. [From the very link you posted](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html) : `By default, the Unity Editor automatically converts Textures to the most appropriate format to match the build target you have selected.`

[This info can all be found in the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/)

Comment: Note: your source file is not altered, the setting effects the *compiled* resource. You can always change the setting, preview the results, and choose differently without having to resave your images.

Comment: Thanks! But when I look at my image I see **RGBA 32 bit** when from the table I linked it should be **RGBA Compressed ETC2** (I have Build target: Android, Format: Automatic, Compression: Normal Quality). Why is that so?

Comment: I think that's due the fact that not all phones support ETC2 ( might not be true in 2019 ) but I think you can enforce it in the export panel where you select the compression